# Diigo functionality similar to SessionManager?

Tags: firefox, diigo, firefox-extensions

Does Diigo have anyway of managing browser session like the [Firefox Session Manager Add-on](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/session-manager/), where you can group urls together (like you can in Diigo with tags), but also open all of them in the browser window at once...switching between sessions to save on memory?

Please let me know if what I am stating is unclear.